# How to limit the amount of pages shown in my related posts snippet

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this code to grab posts written by the same author and display them in a slider. However, I would like to limit the maximum amount of posts it grabs to 4, how would I go and change that? Thanks

```
<div class="author-recent-posts small">
  <div class="author-recent-posts__slider">
    <?php /* $count = 0; */ ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php /* if($count >= 4) break; */ ?>

      <?php $thumb = array(get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/music-background.jpg');

      if (has_post_thumbnail() ):
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
      endif;

      $thumb = sprintf('style="background-image: url(\'%s\')"', esc_url($thumb[0]));
    ?>
    <?php /* $count += 1; */ ?>

    <div class="author-recent-post-item">
      <div class="author-recent-post-item__inner">
        <a class="author-recent-post-item__link" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" rel="bookmark">
          <span class="sr-only"><?php _e('Read more'); ?></span>
        </a>

        <figure class="author-recent-post-item__thumb" <?php echo $thumb; ?>></figure>

        <div class="author-recent-post-item__header">
          <?php the_title('<h3 class="entry-title">', '</h3>'); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure where to start

Comment: There is no JavaScript in this snippet, perhaps this should be tagged with PHP?

Comment: Is this code working, but it is showing more than four posts?  Or is this not working at all?

Comment: It's working, but it's grabbing more than 4